# Linq, SQL, and ISNULL

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.6

I'm trying to figure Linq out. I'm having very little success and most of the articles are for C# which isn't helping.

I'm trying to make the following work;

```
    Dim query = From r In db.eq_list
                Join s In db.interview_main On r.CLIENTCODE Equals s.CLIENTCODE And r.CONTROL Equals s.CONTROL
                Select New With {r.UserName, r.CONTROL, r.CLIENTCODE, r.CLIENTLOCATION, r.IDATETIME, r.FIRSTNAME,
                    r.LASTNAME, If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Code), 0, s.Code)}


    dgvOnHold.DataSource = query.ToList
```

The problem is the IF part. This part can be NULL in the database, but I want it returned as 0 if NULL. I'm putting this into a read-only Datagridview. The original SQL is as follows;

```
SELECT r.ID,r.UserName,r.CONTROL,r.CLIENTCODE,r.CLIENTLOCATION,r.IDATETIME,r.FIRSTNAME,r.LASTNAME,ISNULL(s.CODE,0) AS CODE
FROM system.eq_list AS r
LEFT JOIN interview.main AS s ON r.CLIENTCODE = s.CLIENTCODE AND r.CONTROL = s.CONTROL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't check this at the moment but how about?

```
    Dim query = From r In db.eq_list
            Join s In db.interview_main On r.CLIENTCODE Equals s.CLIENTCODE And r.CONTROL Equals s.CONTROL
            Select New With {r.UserName, r.CONTROL, r.CLIENTCODE, r.CLIENTLOCATION, r.IDATETIME, r.FIRSTNAME,
                r.LASTNAME, If(s.Code is Nothing, 0, s.Code)}


dgvOnHold.DataSource = query.ToList
```

Comment: I get the error: Anonymous type member name can be inferred only from a simple of qualified name with no arguments. -- I added .memberof = before your IF statement. That solved the immediate error, but now it won't let me put the data into the DataGridView.